# Premeasure and sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a set function on a σ-algebra is a measure if and only if it is a premeasure.

Sketch of proof:

A set on σ-algebra is a measure if it is an algebra and given all subsets of the set,the union would still be in the set. By definition of the Caratheodory Extension Theorem, there exists a measure that can be extended to the premeasure. How to link that is my problem

Conversely, if it is a premeasure then a set function on a σ-algebra is a measure. Premeasure is an additive function of sets. Where do I go from here?

So I have been trying my hands on this problem for some time now and can't seem to figure it out. I need someone to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you phrased your question, I think it is a rather trivial exercise and follows directly from the definitions.

A pre-measure on an algebra $\varepsilon$ is a set function $\mu :\varepsilon \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu (\emptyset) = 0$ and for any countable or finite family of disjoint sets $\{A_n\} $ whose union $A=\cup A_n$ is in $\varepsilon$ we have $\sigma$ additivity.

Since a $\sigma$ algebra is an algebra, if $\mu$ is a measure it is a pre-measure. If $\mu$ is a pre-measure on the $\sigma$ algebra, since it is closed under countable union then we have $\sigma$ additivity.

Here you don't need Caratheodory's theorem. Also Caratheodory's theorem says given a premeasure $\rho$ on $\varepsilon$, you can extend it to an outer measure $\mu$ defined on $P(X)$, and the set of all $\mu$ measurable sets form a $\sigma$ algebra $\mathcal{M}$, and the restriction of $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ is a complete measure. In particular all element in $\varepsilon$ are $\mu$ measurable.

Comment: thanks for the help. Yeah! It appears simple as it is. But how to link them is where I struggle with. How does one go about the converse case? Is it as laid out as the first part?

Comment: @user212436 What do you mean by how to link them? If you know $\mu$ is a premeasure on an algebra $\varepsilon$ which is also a $\sigma$ algebra, then you just verify the axioms of a measure.